# ASP.NET 5 kre-version when deploying to Azure via BitBucket

Tags: c#, azure, bitbucket, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using new ASP.NET 5 and I've faced a problem.

I have ASP.NET MVC 6 application. Source code I keep on BitBucket and Azure is my hosting. I linked BitBucket with Azure such that on every push, deploy is launched.

Everything was working great until I updated KRE version to 1.0.0-beta2 (was 1.0.0-beta1).
Now after auto deploy I'm getting **500 Internal Server Error**. But when I publish my application from Visual Studio - it is working without errors.

After investigating files on Azure via FTP I've noticed that when I deploy from Visual Studio my web.config in wwwroot looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta2" />
    <add key="kre-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta2" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="CLR" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\Web" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But after auto deploy from BitBucket it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta2" />
    <add key="kre-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta1" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="CLR" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\Web" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**kre-version** key is different.

Why is it putting beta1 there? Is there any way to specify kre-version explicitly?

Comment: By what process is the `web.config` file being created?

Comment: I think it is created by deploy process which I'm not controlling.

Comment: Are you calling `kpm bundle` or similar anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the same as [Deploying ASP.NET vNext beta 2 on Azure with Kudu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550153/deploying-asp-net-vnext-beta-2-on-azure-with-kudu). Can you try the workaround mentioned there, which is to set a couple app settings (in the Azure portal for the site):

- SCM_KRE_Version=1.0.0-beta2
- SCM_KRE_CLR=CoreCLR