# Deploying ASP.NET vNext beta 2 on Azure with Kudu

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, kudu

According to [this blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/09/deploying-aspnet-vnext-toazure-websites.html), I can deploy vNext apps to Azure using Kudu. I've successfully tried it with vNext beta 1. However, it does not work with vNext beta 2.

Why can't I deploy with vNext beta 2? I thought the whole idea with vNext is that everything (including the CLR) is downloaded as NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem today and the following worked for me:

Set the following environment variables (app settings) in your Azure Web Site:

SCM_KRE_Version   1.0.0-beta2

SCM_KRE_CLR       CoreCLR

**Clarification** SCM_KRE_CLR defaults to the "full" clr, only set SCM_KRE_CLR to CoreCLR if you want to run your website using the new CoreCLR, assuming your site targets ASPNETCORE50 (which has since been renamed to DNXCORE50 after beta3)
[image]