# How to further debug a 500 Internal Server Error after upgrade to ASP.NET 5 beta5

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kudu

I had a site running asp.net 5 beta4, and decided to upgrade to beta5.  The site runs locally fine. I pushed the changes to master and it was picked up from bitbucket and deployed successfully.

When I try to hit the site in azure, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  I've tried a number of things, but can't seem to track down the root cause of the failure.  I'm looking for suggestions as I'm hitting a wall.  From what I've tried below it seems like some fundamental initialization is failing.

Here's what I've tried:

- **Enabling customerrors="off".** I added a web.config to the wwwroot folder with system.web/customErrors mode="Off".  I've verified that the web.config is populated correctly in the deployed wwwroot and had the appsettings containing the dnxversion etc merged correctly.
- **Customizing the custom error page, adding runtimeinfo.** I have the following set in my Startup.cs: 
  `app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");`.  I also have set the error page to display the exception.  This doesn't seem to be hit.
- **Attached to the remote process to debug**.  Visual studio eventually freezes, so haven't gotten anywhere with this.
- **Enabled application insights**.  This registers events when I debug locally, but doesn't capture anything from the azure instance.
- **Enabled application logs and request failure tracing**. The detailed errors show a 500.0, without much detailed information.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0O0X.png)
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlyhq.png)

I've also verified through the console that the runtime is set correctly to beta5.

**Update:**
I set the ASPNET_ENV to Development and it loaded with appsettings loaded via the azure portal. Setting ASPNET_ENV to something else isn't working.  I also removed any custom code from startup.cs pertaining to the non-development environments, with no help.  I'm still looking for a means of capturing the original error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are targeting DNX451 and not dnxcore50, there is a good chance Azure it still trying to run it against the beta4 runtime instead of beta5.  If that's the case, you won't get a decent error message.

Try adding an environment variable in Azure "SCM_DNX_VERSION" and set it to 1.0.0-beta5.  It looks like kudu was recently upgraded to support beta5 https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/commit/55175a017779bf493ff8e6ce87b96dd1451f7d7b, so you might want to try to redeploy from bitbucket in the case that the Kudu team has already deployed this change.

For a little more detail, you can check out my previous answer (although it is very dated and references the old "K" names) here:

[Deploying ASP.NET vNext beta 2 on Azure with Kudu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550153/deploying-asp-net-vnext-beta-2-on-azure-with-kudu)

Every time you update to a new beta, you will have to update your SCM_DNX_VERSION environment variable.

Comment: It looks like the kudu team is working on reading this out of global.json.  Many would consider this a better approach because you won't have to go around and update a bunch of environment variables every time you use a new ASPNET5 version. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1623